# image with four clickable areas

Tags: android, android-button

[image]

Here is what I am trying to do. I am creating a drag and drop controller. Users are able to move the controls where they want on the screen to save it. I have everything else done, except this. I have thought of a couple different ideas to get this to work, but most of them do not work so well with the drag and drop feature.

I have created an XML file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/dpad_up"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/dpad_down"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dpad_up"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/dpad_left"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dpad_right"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/dpad_up"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/dpad_right"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dpad_up"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/d_pad"
        android:background="@drawable/d_pad"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dpad_down"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dpad_left"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/dpad_right" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I was thinking of using that XML bring into my activity and do a drag and drop, but I am not sure how I could do that. Any ideas or help would be great. I just need to be able to perform a drag and drop and have each of the directions buttons register when pressed to perform the action.

Answer (score 0):

Invisible views are not touchable.

Just change `Button` into `View` or `Space`, and let it visible.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. assign it to a relativelayout and attach the ondraglistener to it, or is there a better way?